# dependency injection for interfaces

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a component which contains a generic popup, it implements therefore the interface **PopupParent**

```
@Injectable()
@Component(
    //...
)
class SubjectListComponent implements OnInit, PopupParent {
}
```

The generic class **InfoPopup** needs to deal abstractly with its parent (that implements **PopupParent**), so I would like to take get the parent injected by its interface (instead of being injected by its concrete class **SubjectListComponent**)

```
class InfoPopup {
  final PopupParent _parent;

  InfoPopup(this._parent);
  //...non relevant code
}
```

The issue is that the **SubjectListComponent** was registred by class in the injector, so the injector won't find what to inject into the **InfoPopup** class.

If I try to declare my **SubjectListComponent** manually, I found that it has to be done in the providers constants. but I still don't have my instance of **SubjectListComponent** when I declare my component...

How could I do that?

I also tried to pass the parent to an @Input:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'info-popup',
    templateUrl: 'info_popup.html',
    styleUrls: const ['info_popup.css'],
)
class InfoPopup {
  @Input()
  final PopupParent parent;

  InfoPopup(this._parent);
  //...non relevant code
}
```

But then I got stuck on how to inject the **this** instance from the component client :

subject_list_comp.html:

```
<div>
  <info-popup [parent]="this"></info-popup>
</div>
```

since dart angular doesn't recognize **this** as a keyword, but it searches for a property called **this** in SubjectListComponent.dart

Two issues were created for this question:
https://github.com/dart-lang/site-webdev/issues/514
https://github.com/dart-lang/site-webdev/issues/515

Comment: `@Injectable()` on a `@Component()` is redundant.

Comment: Ok good o know, but I added @ Injectable out of despair since I get a "No provider for PopupParent!"

I also tried to push the parent as an @ Input, but angular dart doesn't understand the keyword 'this' in the template

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "push the parent" or "understand the keyword 'this'". If you provide more info, I'm sure I can solve some more misunderstandings ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by providing aliases. `multi: true` allows to add more than one alias. There is no way to make automatically derive the interfaces.

```
@Component(
  providers: [
      const Provider(PopupParent, useExisting: SubjectListComponent, multi: true),
      const Provider(PopupParent, useExisting: FooComponent, multi: true)

  ]
)
class InfoPoupup ...
```

**update**

To make

```
[parent]="this"
```

work, you could add a getter to the component

```
get self => this;
```

and then use

```
[parent]="self"
```

Comment: This is an acceptable solution, but it makes InfoPopup know the existence of PopupComponent (so it can't really be used as a library component). I hope dart allows a better mean to do that

Comment: That's already better than what TS allows, because TS doesn't support interfaces at all. I don't think there is currently a different way.

Comment: Isn' it possible to attribute it an injection name (or to pass the instance of PopupParent as an input?)

Comment: I don't see a way using an injection name. Passing to an input might work, but for that I would need more information. Can you please add the code to your question that shows what you tried with the other approaches you mentioned.

Comment: To make `[parent]="this"` work, you could add a getter to the component `get self => this;` and then use `[parent]="self"`

Comment: I didn't try it since I have to solve my issue for tomorrow, but I believe your solution would work.

Maybe that should be the answer I validate if you mind doing another answer (for the next persons in my situation)

Comment: An maybe I should add an issue for angular dart to support the "this" keyword : it is anyway a non sens for the angular engine to search for a property called "this"